# How can I set default storage engine used by MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I've been working on writing SQL to create a MySQL database with several default options, including character set and collation.  Is it possible to set the default storage engine for tables in this database to InnoDB?

I've been looking through the MySQL 5.1 manual and I've found the statement `ENGINE=innodb` which would be appended to a `CREATE TABLE` statement, but I haven't found anything related to a `CREATE DATABASE` statement.

Is there a normal way to do this as part of the database creation, or does it need to be specified on a table-by-table basis?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Quoting the Reference Manual ([Setting the Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-setting.html)):

> If you omit the `ENGINE` option, the default storage engine is used. Normally, this is MyISAM, but you can change it by using the **`--default-storage-engine`** server startup option, or by setting the **`default-storage-engine`** option in the **`my.cnf`** configuration file.

The default-storage-engine option must be part of the mysqld section in **my.cnf**;

```
[mysqld]
default-storage-engine = innodb
```

You may also want to change the default storage engine just for the current session. You can do this by setting the `storage_engine` variable:

```
SET storage_engine=INNODB;
```

Comment: Note, you have to reset mysql for the changes to my.cnf to take effect. Pretty obvious but it tripped me up.

Comment: For setting this in my.cnf, I guess it should go in the [mysqld] section, or does it matter?

Comment: Note in mysql >=5.7.9 you must use default_storage_engine

Comment: what is the default engine for MySQL?

Comment: Is `default-storage-engine` or `default_storage_engine` ?

Answer (score 8):

you need to specify the default storage engine when starting mysqld. for example:

```
mysqld --default-storage-engine=InnoDB
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_default-storage-engine

Comment: I should have been more clear... I'm aware of how to specify using InnoDB from the CREATE TABLE statements, and using the startup options, and by amending my.cnf.  I'm specifically asking about whether it is possible to do as part of a CREATE DATABASE statement in an SQL script.