# Create innodb database in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I tried to create a database type of innodb.I tried this query but its not exectuted. 
CREATE DATABASE "mydd" ENGINE = InnoDB 
I checked the configuration and it says innodb enabled. I also searched in web but only ended up 
 with creatin innodb tables.
I set the database as innodb then all the table
under this will takes the same type and no need to specify again.Also my defauld engine should not be innodb.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3050492/632951

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you can specify Engine while creating database.

because one database can have multiple engine type tables in it

Check create database command at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html

Answer (score 12):

Check the syntax for CREATE DATABASE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-database.html

> CREATE {DATABASE | SCHEMA} [IF NOT
>   EXISTS] db_name
>       [create_specification] ...
>
> create_specification:
>       [DEFAULT] CHARACTER SET [=] charset_name   | [DEFAULT] COLLATE [=]
>   collation_name

You can change the default storage engine on starting up mysql, or during your session. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html

> If you omit the ENGINE or TYPE option,
>   the default storage engine is used.
>   Normally, this is MyISAM, but you can
>   change it by using the
>   --default-storage-engine or --default-table-type server startup option, or by setting the
>   default-storage-engine or
>   default-table-type option in the
>   my.cnf configuration file.
>
> You can set the default storage engine
>   to be used during the current session
>   by setting the storage_engine or
>   table_type variable:
>
> SET storage_engine=MYISAM; SET
>   table_type=BDB;
>
> When MySQL is installed on Windows
>   using the MySQL Configuration Wizard,
>   the InnoDB or MyISAM storage engine
>   can be selected as the default. See
>   Section 2.10.3.5, “The Database Usage
>   Dialog”.

Comment: Latest versions have **default_storage_engine** variable

Answer (score -1):

Hi normally programmers use innodb for table don't know if you can set it for database
refer

[Database creation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-database.html)