# MySQL:START TRANSACTION - UPDATE - ROLLBACK : Non-Transactional Tables

Tags: mysql, transactions, subquery, rollback, savepoints

I'm attempting to run these queries to perform a ROLLBACK, and I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong, but I get a warning:

> Some non-transactional changed tables couldn't be rolled back.

After a bit of research I found that the most likely cause for this message is the false assumption that a table is transactional, but is actually not. How does one determine which tables are transactional?

I have to assume that the database I'm using uses rollback because it's in the assignment that I'm given for the class that requires us to use the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables that use the InnoDB storage engine, or those using the NDB cluster storage engine, support transactions; the other engines do not. (There's a comparison table somewhere in the documentation, but I can't find it right now.)

To check a specific table, use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>;
```

which will show you the complete `CREATE TABLE` statement, including the `ENGINE` clause.

To check which engines are installed in your database, use

```
SHOW ENGINES;
```

If you have InnoDB installed but it is not the default engine, you can either specify `ENGINE=InnoDB` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement or change it later with

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Notice also that the default engine for MySQL is **not** InnoDB if your version is older than 5.5; check here for some options of setting InnoDB as the default engine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050492/how-can-i-set-default-storage-engine-used-by-mysql

Comment: Thank you, this helped me figure out the engine was MyISAM, which kind of sucks. Now I get it.

Comment: Oh, by the way your solution was excellent. Both solutions were good to know, of course. :)